# Creating a pull request using the API of GitHub

Tags: github

I'm trying to make a pull request to GitHub using it's REST API directly, using this documentation:

https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request

I have created a public repo, and I try the operation of the retrieve of the pull requests by the API, and works fine.
But when I try to create a pull request using this operation:

```
POST /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls
```

and this body:

```
    {
  "title": "Amazing new feature",
  "body": "Please pull this in!",
  "head": "theOwner:new-branch",
  "base": "master"
}
```

then I receive this message from the response:

```
{
    "message": "Not Found",
    "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request"
}
```

The full url that I make the request is:

https://api.github.com/repos/alvarocallero/node-test/pulls

Is right the body of the request that I'm using?
May be the value of "head" is not the correct one.

Comment: 404 indicates api not found. What exactly are the values of owner and repo u r passing?

Comment: This is the url: https://api.github.com/repos/alvarocallero/node-test/pulls, owner is 'alvarocallero' and repo is 'node-test'

Comment: Is the branch in the same repo in which you are creating the pull request?

Comment: @Yug yes it is.

Comment: I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I created a `feature` branch in the same repository against whom I wanted to create a Pull request. After that I invoked the api `POST /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls` as mentioned in the question with the following body:

```
{
  "title": "Amazing new feature",
  "body": "Please pull this in!",
  "head": "feature",
  "base": "master"
}
```

As you can see since my `feature` branch is in the same repo as the master against whom I am creating a Pull request I just mentioned it's name in the `head`.

After this I also ensured that I pass `Authorization`(Basic Auth ) and when I invoked the API the Pull request was created in the github.

Then I tried invoking the above API without passing the Authorization header and I got `404`. Therefore I think you need to correct `head` value in the body as you mentioned in the comment that your branch is in the same repo as that of master against whom you are creating a Pull request. And make sure to pass the `Authorization header`

Comment: I used Bearer as Authorization with the token that I get from an App setted up on my gitHub account, but I still get a 404 not found..

Comment: By the way, I also put in the head field only the name of the new branch

Comment: @Alvaro I used basic authorization with username and password encoded as base64.

Comment: I was not using the correct password: instead of using the accessToken with the userName, I used my password of git, that was the mistake. Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After using Basic Authentication as @Yug Sing suggest, then I can finally make the PR via API: my problem was that on the creation on the token for the basic auth, instead of using userName and accessToken, I used userName and my password of git, so the authentication fails